# Where do I put files in a nuget package so that they will be restored?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, dacpac

I'm working on setting up nuget packages for dacpacs for some large database schemas we have.  Here's a sample of the metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>xxxx.DACPAC</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>xxxxDatabase dacpac</title>
    <authors>xxxxxxxxx</authors>
    <owners>xxx</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <projectUrl>xxx-database.git</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://github.com/contoso/UsefulStuff/nuget_icon.png</iconUrl>
    <description>DACPAC for xxxx Database</description>
    <releaseNotes>Initial release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright ©2019 xxxx</copyright>
    <tags>dacpac database xxxxxx</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

The .nupkg looks like this
[image]

and the content directory like this:

[image]

This works fine.  I then create a solution with an ssdt project and a skeleton c# project.  I use the c# project to hold the dacpacs.  I can nuget them, then in the ssdt project add database refs pointing to the dacpacs.  The dacpacs are not in git (part of my goal is to keep them out).

I commit the repo then clone it to an empty directory.  Good so far.

Next, i use nuget to restore the packages in visual studio.   However the dacpacs are not restored!  I think that's because they are in the "content" directory in the package and from what I can find, those files are not restored by nuget.

So, my question is, where to put these files so that they *will* be restored?  Which nupkg directory?  Content doesn't work.  Tried tools to no avail.  Thought I should ask before another blind attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, my question is, where to put these files so that they will be
>   restored? Which nupkg directory? Content doesn't work. Tried tools to
>   no avail. Thought I should ask before another blind attempt.

`Nuget Restore` is to download the mssing packages. And the content in `xx.nupkg` will only be added to projects at **install time** of one package. `Nuget restore` can't get the content files back, that's not restore's job. So it has nothing to do with which directory we put the files in, it's just one not supported job for `nuget restore`...

**As a workaround:** You can use `Update-Package -reinstall` in `Package Manager Console` to reinstall the package. And the content files will be added back to project. More details see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages#using-update-package). Hope it helps :)